# Help with notation for set definition: $\{ j : A_j \in A_1\}$

Tags: notation

$\{ j : A_j \in A_1\}$ where $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$ are defined.

I understand the elementary notation but can't quite see how the set is supposed to be defined. Is this supposed to be the set of all the defined sets above which are in $A_1$?

Comment: It is the set of indices of the sets which are elements of $A_1$.

Comment: @JohnDouma Would you please elaborate? It means just all natural numbers which are in $A_1$? That doesn't quite make sense to me.

Comment: As written, your set consists of $j$s. The $j$s are the indices for the $A$s. The $A$s in which we are interested are those which are elements of $A_1$ which, evidently, is a set.

Comment: @JohnDouma Thank you, I understand now.

Comment: @JohnDouma you can post that as an answer if you like, to which the OP may $\color{green}{\checkmark \mbox{Accept}}$ it! :P